# SpringBoot Project build failure with Open JDK 11.0.2 in Intellij 2019.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded my project from Oracle JDK8 to OpenJDK 11.0.2

Java Version in my system

```
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

When I build my project using maven from the terminal it compiles fine but is failing while building the same using IntelliJ. There is no stack trace to look upon, every time I build the project it shows me this error.

This says it's a NullPointerException and I know we have lots of duplicate questions on SO for the same, I am not asking to resolve NullPointer but instead if someone can help me just figure out a way to check the logs while building the project using **play** button in IntelliJ, I will help myself afterward.

[image]

I checked the idea.log file and there is nothing to be suspicious about.

```
019-04-30 16:44:54,956 [1342048]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/Users/neeraj/Projects/office/PartnerPortal' PartnerPortallibraryTable took 19 ms
2019-04-30 16:44:54,995 [1342087]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS)
2019-04-30 16:44:55,154 [1342246]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/neeraj/Projects/office/PartnerPortal
2019-04-30 16:44:56,433 [1343525]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 51 ms
2019-04-30 16:44:57,683 [1344775]   INFO - over.idea.build.CloverCompiler - External build - file generated: outputRoot=</Users/neeraj/Projects/office/PartnerPortal/target/classes> relativePath=<META-INF/PartnerPortal.kotlin_module>
2019-04-30 16:44:58,102 [1345194]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 1; warnings: 0 took 3111 ms: 0 min 3sec
2019-04-30 16:44:58,103 [1345195]   INFO - over.idea.build.CloverCompiler - CLOVER: COMPILATION IN EXTERNAL BUILD PROCESS HAS FINISHED
2019-04-30 16:44:58,106 [1345198]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened
2019-04-30 16:44:58,455 [1345547]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/classes.zip
2019-04-30 16:44:58,486 [1345578]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2019-04-30 16:44:58,486 [1345578]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2019-04-30 16:44:58,486 [1345578]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2019-04-30 16:44:59,360 [1346452]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
2019-04-30 16:44:59,360 [1346452]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
2019-04-30 16:44:59,360 [1346452]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
2019-04-30 16:44:59,360 [1346452]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
2019-04-30 16:44:59,361 [1346453]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-04-30 16:45:04,513 [1351605]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 47 ms
2019-04-30 16:45:21,297 [1368389]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 41 ms
```

Comment: Do you have " Atlassian Clover for IDEA" plugin enabled? Please try to disable it.

Comment: and it worked somehow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling "Atlassian Clover for IDEA" plugin helped in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to

`<arg>-J--permit-illegal-access</arg>`

flag in maven-compiler-plugin.
Checking intelij logs also helps
Help -> Collect logs and diagnostics data
in InteliJ menu